# Why vortex lines should only end on themselves?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vortex

This is the Helmholtz theorem. Vortex lines never end on the fluid.

What is the physical reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply another way of saying $\nabla\cdot \nabla \times\vec{u} = 0$ for a vector field at any point where $\vec{u}$ is $C^2$. The vorticity $\vec{\omega} = \nabla\times \vec{u}$ is a divergenceless field because it is the curl of the velocity field.

Comment: In other words, there is no *physical* reason. This is a kinematical theorem and as such belongs in the realm of mathematics.

Comment: @Pirx If you have the nice habit of smoking, move your fingers through the smoke and you will see that the smoke reattaches again. There must be some physical reason for this.

Comment: I don't smoke, but I'm a theoretical fluid dynamicist. What do you think those whiffs of smoke have to do with vortex lines?

Comment: Thank you, I agree with you. But what is the reason for this?

Comment: @Pirx I smoke I like it or not because I am a  welder. You know better than me that this smoke is deep in the regime of turbulence.

Comment: No, it's not. Those Reynolds numbers are far too low; what you are seeing is typically fully laminar flow.